# Files vs Database for Lua on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, lua

I have an iPhone app I'm writing which uses Lua. My question is in regards to the Lua routines. Should I keep them in an SQLite database, or a file.

I am leaning towards database because of the following perceived benefits:
1. I open the database once only, whereas with a file I have to reopen each time I want that routine. This makes it faster?
2. Easier to transfer/save the routines as they are all in one file
3. Neater file structure.

Anyone faced the same situation before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already use the database for something, then by all means, you can use it to store the lua procedures too.

If you have the database only for storing lua procedures, then it is probably a bit overkill.

Answer (score 2):

> I open the database once only, whereas with a file I have to reopen each time I want that routine. This makes it faster?

Why are you discarding the routine in the first place? Once you've loaded your script(s) into a Lua state, there's no need to hit the file system again, unless a script calls dofile/loadfile/etc., right?

> Easier to transfer/save the routines as they are all in one file

But to read/write the scripts *within* that file you need to execute SQL statements, right? Seems like it would be a pain in the butt, rather than make anything easier.

> Neater file structure.

If you're going to use dofile/loadfile/require in your scripts, you'll need to hook them to look in the database instead.

Is this question prompted by a performance problem you're having, or is it a hypothetical? I'm a big fan of [keeping it simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), so I wouldn't do anything like this unless you need to and it produces a measurable performance gain (I don't imagine it would).

Comment: I don't ask hypotheticals. Both structures are already built and in place.